# Writing an if-statement inside of return

Tags: java

I want to write a program in java that calculates the squareroot and I am not allowed to use the math module

My code is

```
public class Quadratwurzel

public static double quadratwurzel(double x, int n) {
return(if (n == 0){x+1/2} else{0.5*quadratwurzel(x,n-1)+x/quadratwurzel(x,n-1)})}
```

I am hoping someone can explain me why I cannot write an if/else statment inside of return because in my lecture notes it says that we have to write a statement inside of return and the statment gets substituated with the parameters.

I.e if I start the method or function

```
quadratwurzel(32.0,6)
```

Then the body of the function which is inside of return will be substituated with:

```
(32.0,6)
```

And because

```
6!=1,5!=1,...2!=1
```

The method would be started 5 times again recursively until it termintates.

That is my idea and I was wondering why the substitution here does not work like that.

I hope somebody can help and give me the correct code for the idea

Comment: `return` requires an expression (or nothing at all for void) not a statement

Comment: is if/else statement not an expression?

Comment: thats a statement

Comment: Expression returns value, if..else doesn't return anything, it executes specified code blocks.

Comment: Definition of expressions :Let S' be the set of all sorts we take a finite subset S of S'. Let F be the set of operations of the form S_1X...XS_n -> S_n+1 where n is finite and all S_i are in S. A variable v in S_k is an expression in S_k, a constant $\emptyset\rifghtarrow S_k$ where S_k $\in$ S is an expression in S_k, and if op is in F with op:S_1X...XS_n -> S_n+1  and $a_1,...a_n$ are expressions in S_1,,,,,S_n then op(a_1,...,a_n) is an expr. in S_n+1. Finally if b is an expr of the sort boolean and a_1,a_2 are expr in S_0 then if b then a_1 else a_2 is an expr. of the sort S_0

Comment: therefore I don't understand why an if/else statement is not an expression. Can you please tell me what is the difference between an expressions and a statement? If...else also returns a value. Why do you say it does not yield a value?

Comment: @RM777 I updated my answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the ternary operator:

```java
return condition ? value1 : value2;
```

Comment: The `if` code would work just fine if it were syntactically valid.  Switching it to another syntax doesn't really improve things.

Comment: @Makoto [I beg to differ](https://tio.run/##dY1BDoMgEEXX9RSzhDQ1ZW2v0JXLxgVVNGMRDQwmDeHsFGm3/YvJT17m/Vnu8jIPr5R6LZ2Du0QTKshxJAl7QEMwetOzoyCHUJ2sIm9NwJHhTfCAZxFBaacCxtiU31ju5p86G36ifcUBlqxnLVk006MDaSdXjO3bkVrq1VO9ZaYNK5OC8@YvvB7wO1bFlD4)

Comment: The code you provided *wasn't* syntactically valid, though.  You may want to peruse my answer for clarification.

Comment: The reason why I accepted this answer is that it points out  the syntax of a conditional expression which is contrary to the intuitive approach not if/else... What if/else actually is, is another story

Comment: What for nested if else ?

Answer (score 4):

[The syntax for `return`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) requires [an expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8).  An `if`-statement [is a **statement**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) and thus cannot be used as the target of a `return` expression.

This would mean you need to change your code to this:

```
public static double quadratwurzel(double x, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return x + 1 / 2;
    } else {
        return 0.5 * quadratwurzel(x, n - 1) + x / quadratwurzel(x, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Note that there's an integer division problem here which I must leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: ++ for actually explaining problem. BTW it may be worth introducing conditional operator which is form of expression which is similar to if..else.

Comment: @Pshemo:  I don't really think so; I'd rather espouse a circumstance in which readable code can then be converted by tooling (like an IDE) into something else.  Also, ternaries are going to make debugging or diagnosing the integer division problem *that* much harder...

Comment: My suggestion was based on "*because in my lecture notes it says that we **have to write a statement inside of return***" which IMO may mean that OP should write code in form `return [logic which creates result];` which is like asking for conditionally operator, but I may be wrong here.

Comment: I am sorry I confused statement with expression what is the difference? Variables, Constants and applied Operations we have defined as expressions. Furthermore we have also defined that the if...else statement is also the syntax for another expression. In the lecture note we have said: if b is an expr of the sort boolean and a_1,a_2 are expr in S_0 then "if b then a_1 else a_2" is an expr. of the sort S_0- See also in the comments beneath the question for more elaborate definition of expressions

Comment: I've added some more links in my answer to help clarify @RM777.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional statement, which is kind of like a hard to read if statement.

```
return n == 0 ? x+1/2 : 0.5*quadratwurzel(x,n-1)+x/quadratwurzel(x,n-1);
```

Comment: I'm disagreeing with this answer precisely because it's "hard to read".  It also doesn't really do a job of educating others as to why the other `return` syntax wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the conditional operator here. Read more at this [link](https://www.w3schools.in/java-tutorial/operators/conditional/)

```
return n == 0 ? x+1/2 : (0.5*quadratwurzel(x,n-1)+x/quadratwurzel(x,n-1));
```

Comment: well that's awkward

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that *should* fix your problem. I cannot test if it produces the expected result because I don't have your full program.

```
public class Quadratwurzel

public static double quadratwurzel(double x, int n) {
    if (n == 0){
        return (x+1/2);
    }else{
        return 0.5*quadratwurzel(x,n-1)+x/quadratwurzel(x,n-1);
    }}
```

The reason you cannot put an if statement is `return` is because `return` requires something *to return*, meaning, it only knows how to feedback a value or an object. It is not capable of "thinking" or performing the logic in an if statement. This is true for the Java programming language (consistent with your request), but not for other languages like Python, as indicated by @ in the comments below.

Therefore, you must determine what must be returned *before* you issue the return statement, which is how I edited your code above.

**UPDATE TO OP COMMENT**
"therefore I don't understand why an if/else statement is not an expression. Can you please tell me what is the difference between an expressions and a statement? If...else also returns a value. Why do you say it does not yield a value?"

A very simple way to describe a statement vs an expression, is that:
**A statement** will *do something*, it will complete an action. So in the example of an `IF condition THEN action`, the if *statement* performs the action of evaluating a logical condition and returning a value. An expression is something that holds a value, like: `2` or `False`  or `5+3`

Per [this article](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-an-expression-in-Python-Why-is-print-%E2%80%98hi%E2%80%99-a-statement-while-other-functions-are-expressions), a good way to think about it is if you can print it or assign it to a variable, it is an expression. Otherwise, it is a statement.

Comment: Other languages - like Python - are capable of expressing `return x if x else y`, which doesn't *quite* make your answer satisfactory.  I believe your answer would be better if it were more based in Java and not really in theory.

Comment: That is true. I explicitly assumed that it would be for Java-only type answers. I will make a note that this is true for the Java case but not universal. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Also, semicolons.  You're missing semicolons.

Comment: @JerryM.  I have read Makoto's comment to this post and I have to ask you something: In Phython if...else is an expression and in JAVA it is a statement?

Comment: Not quite. Both @Makoto and I both indicate that `If...Else` is always a statement, since it evaluates a condition. In both languages, by definition, it is a statement. You cannot assign `If...Else` to a variable.

Comment: but what about haskell (functional programing)? Java is not a functional programming language the lecture note says that static methods are used to simulate functional programming, can you make a comment on this based on this example in the context with if/else statements?

Comment: The programming language in the semantics case does not matter, even for the Haskell example which is supported here (http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/07/statements-vs-expressions.html). The important thing to remember is that a `statement`, regardless of language, evaluates a condition. An `expression` holds a value, or does something with a value (or object).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple ternary operation

```java
return n == 0 ? //
    x + 1/2 : //
    0.5 * quadratwurzel(x, n - 1) + x / quadratwurzel(x, n - 1);

// NB: I usually use formatting (here, with double slash comments) to ease code reading
```

Comment: Why do people think ternary is "simple"?  This makes the code entirely unintelligible.

Answer (score -1):

You can, but you're using it wrong.

```
public int foo(int a, int b){
        return a > b ? a + b : a - b;
    }
```

a > b followed with a ? is the conditional, the first phrase after the ? is what gets returned if the conditional is true, and the second part, after the : is what gets returned if the conditional is false.

Answer (score -1):

you can use either

```
return (n == 0) ? (x+1/2) : (0.5*quadratwurzel(x,n-1)+x/quadratwurzel(x,n-1));
```

or

```
    public static double quadratwurzel(double x, int n) {
        if (n != 0){
            double quadratwurzel_val = quadratwurzel(x,n-1);
            return 0.5*quadratwurzel_val+x/quadratwurzel_val;
        }
        return (x+1/2);
    }
```

but the second approach is better as it doesn't call quadratwurzel(x,n-1) 2 times